# Java Mail: How to add a Message inside another message

Tags: jakarta-mail, message, email-attachments

I need to add a message as an email attachment to another message(MimeMessage) in java mail.  Both parent and attachment messages are created on the fly.  I couldn't get any references of how to do this.  Can somebody give a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JavaMail FAQ:

- [How do I forward a message?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#forward)